# Use S3 bucket to serve multiple websites using single cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket which contains two folders `my-experience` and `test-experience` both of these folders contains a website. I want to use CloudFront distribution to serve websites from these folders. I want to achieve this:

I want to create a distribution of S3 bucket with the default root object of `index.html` and then, when a user goes to `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net/test-experience` I want to serve my website from the `test-experience` folder and when he goes to `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net/my-experience` I want to serve website from `my-experience` folder.

*What I did:*

> I created an S3 bucket and then created folders inside the bucket. the root was empty.
>
> I created a cloudfront distribution for my bucket and set the default root object to index.html.
>
> Now when I go the cloudfront link I don't get anything. I also tried creating different origins.

Answer (score 2):

The default root object only applies when requesting the **root** url, in your case when requesting `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net` or `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net/`.

If you want to redirect `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net/my-experience` to `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net/my-experience/index.html` or `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net/test-experience` to `awd729398dh3d.cloudfront.net/test-experience/index.html` you will need to rewrite the URL with an [Origin Request Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html) function:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const { request } = event.Records[0].cf;

  // Rewrite uri if needed
  if (/\/my-experience\/?$/.test(request.uri)) request.uri = '/my-experience/index.html';
  if (/\/test-experience\/?$/.test(request.uri)) request.uri = '/test-experience/index.html';

  callback(null, request);
};
```